# Showing data from bubble sort in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, bubble-sort

I'm tried to sort the database from a web service by using the bubble sort.

```
itemLists[i] = new ItemList(
                            a.getString(id),
                            a.getString(nama),
                            a.getString(latitude),
                            a.getString(longitude),
                            a.getString(alamat));
                    double terendah = Double.valueOf(a.getString("TAG_TERENDAH")).doubleValue();
                    //double terendah = a.getDouble(terenda);
                    harga[i] = terendah;
                    //bubble sort
                    double tHarga;
                    ItemList tItemList;

                    for (int k = 0; k < tempatrental.length(); k++) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < tempatrental.length() - (k + 1); l++) {
                            if (harga[l] > harga[l + 1]) {
                                tHarga = harga[l];
                                tItemList = itemLists[l];


                                harga[l] = harga[l + 1];
                                itemLists[l] = itemLists[l + 1];


                                harga[l + 1] = tHarga;
                                itemLists[l + 1] = tItemList;

                            }

                        }
```

Anyways, database from the web service is array type, so I store it in the array from another class.

```
public class ItemList{

public String label1, label2, label3, label4, label5;

public ItemList(String label1, String label2, String label3, String label4, String label5) {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //this.icon = icon;
    this.label1 = label1;
    this.label2 = label2;
    this.label3 = label3;
    this.label3 = label4;
    this.label3 = label5;

}
```

The problem came when I tried to show the results of sorting in the list view.

```
this.setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(TermurahActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemLists));
```

Eclipse says : The Constructor ArrayAdapter(TermurahActivity, int, ItemList[]) is undefined. Please help fix to fix this...

Comment: Why BubbleSort, which is the **least efficient** sorting algorithm? Can't you try QuickSort? Or, better, use the Java `native sorting` methods provided by the collection objects?

Answer (score 0):

Once you defined `ArrayAdapter<String>` the adapter expects a list of `String`.

`ItemLists` is a list of `ItemList` so you should use:

```
  new ArrayAdapter<ItemList>(TermurahActivity.this, 
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemLists);`
```